# How can I pass data from Activity to BottomSheet Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am confused about the use of fragment in BottomSheet. I used this tutorial: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-bottomsheet-in-kotlin

This thing itself basically works - BottomSheet shows up and hides whenever I want, **but I want to pass some data there dynamically**, according to the item that I click on from the list.

This is how it works in code according to the tutorial:

```
// Fragment creation
var bottomSheetFragment : Fragment? = null
bottomSheetFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.filter_fragment)

// Behavior configuration
private var mBottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View?>? = null
bottomSheetFragment?.let {
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(it.view)?.let { bsb ->
            bsb.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
            mBottomSheetBehavior = bsb
        }
    }
}

// How we show and hide it
fun show(){
   mBottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}

fun hide(){
   mBottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
}
```

So, there it works and there's no fragment object where I can use NewInstance to pass the data as I usually do. How can I do it in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you can use bundle to pass data from activity to fragment like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String myMessage = "Stack Overflow is cool!";
bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
FragmentClass fragInfo = new FragmentClass();
fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
```

in the fragment you can access this bundle

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
 savedInstanceState) {
  String myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");
   ...
  }
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct response. It worked and solved a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You can add `BottomSheetFragment` in your `nav_graph` and pass data as an argument of `action`.

```kotlin
findNavController().navigate(
   MyFragmentDirections.actionMyFragmentToBottomSheetDialog(myData)
)
```

And finally, get the result as mentioned in [the document](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result).